# feasible to not declare ivar but use in synthesize?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I'm looking at some sample code and I'm puzzled over the lack of declaration of a specific ivar. Hoping someone can help me understand this better:

```
typedef NSUInteger (^NumberOfItemsInSection)(ViewClass *viewClass, NSUInteger section);

// class declaration    
@interface SampleScrollView : UIScrollView
@property (nonatomic, copy) NumberOfItemsInSection itemsSectionBlock;
@end

// class implementation
@implementation SampleScrollView

@synthesize itemsSectionBlock = _itemsSectionBlock;

- (void)setItemsSectionBlock:(NumberOfItemsInSection)itemsSectionBlock
{
    // _itemsSectionBlock is not declared any where in the class 
    // How does the compiler not complain?

    _itemsSectionBlock = [itemsSectionBlock copy];
    [self reloadData];
}

@end
```

The instance variable, "_itemsSectionBlock", is not declared any where and it can just be used in the property's setter override. How does that work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's part of the modern runtime, and cuts down on the duplication of code - declaring iVars and then declaring properties for those iVars.

It's handled for you by the `@synthesize`

The modern runtime lets you do other things that you thought you couldn't do before. For example, you can now declare iVars in the .m file as part of a class extension, which reduces the amount of information you expose in your public interface.

**Update**

The modern LLVM 4 compiler even lets you do away with the @sytnthesize line. If you declare a property it will auto-synthesize for you and it will even create a backing store with a leading underscore.

Comment: Will this make the ability to define pure private members ? Could the iVar be forgotten forever using this pinciple ?

Comment: You can always have pure private members using the `@private` declaration as long as you don't expect those iVars to be KVC/KVO compliant. As soon as you declare setters and getters for them, then they are accessible using methods, and there is no concept of private methods in Objective-C. And yes, I've mostly done away declaring iVars in my classes.

Comment: getters and setters can be declared in the private interface (in the .m) so they keep private from outside. And you don't have the problem of KVC/KVO restriction anymore.

Comment: @Oliver - It doesn't matter that they are declared in the private interface, you can still call them from outside the class. Methods cannot be private in Objective-C.

Comment: Yes, of course, you can call them. But I mean that they are not visible. So you must know what to call.

Comment: Yes, but I mean for yourself, avoiding access of members you didn't want to be public... for yourself... while you are coding with hundred of files you've written monthes ago.